# Prove that $A\setminus A=\varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that, $A\setminus A=\varnothing$

This is a question relating to sets.

Here, $A$ can be any set and I know that any set minus the same set equals to a set with no elements.

I do understand that any set minus the same set is of course equal to 0. But I was supposed to prove this for my maths assignment.

But I do not know how to prove this. Please help me.

Comment: Do you also know that $\emptyset$ is the set with no elements? If so, you apparently know that $A\setminus A=\emptyset$.

Comment: generally you will get more help (especially help from which you will profit much more) if you add some of your own thoughts to the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case where everything follows directly from the very definition. we have
$$
A\setminus B:=\{x:x\in A\wedge x\notin B\}
$$
and for $A=B$ we have therefore
$$
A\setminus A:=\{x:x\in A\wedge x\notin A\}
$$
which means, that for any $x\in A$ we also need that $x\notin A$ which of course holds for no $x\in A$. Therefore the set of elements, which lie in $A\setminus A$ is empty and we write
$$
A\setminus A:=\{x:x\in A\wedge x\notin A\}=\emptyset
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Can there be a point $a$ with both $a\in A$ and $a\notin A$?

Comment: Yes but how can that be?

Comment: Exactly, it *can't* be. There is no point $a$ with $a\in A$ and $a\notin A$. In other words, there does not exist a point in $A\setminus A$. That's the same as saying $A\setminus A$ is the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

Assume there exists $x \in A \setminus A$. Then $x \in A$ but $x\notin A$. This is a contradiction, thus there exists no $x \in A \setminus A$, which means that the set is empty